# Unable to carry out operations (create trigger, drop table) for a table I created

Tags: sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database with SQL Server Management Studio where I have existing tables. I add a few tables to it and it works just fine. However, for subsequent operations such as

```
Drop table XXX --OR 
Create Trigger YYY on XXX
```

I run into a error statement that reads:

> i) Cannot drop table XXX as it does not exist or you do not have permissions
>
> ii) The object 'XXX' does not exist or is invalid for this operation

I tried to carry out an Insert operation but that showed me a similar error (The object 'XXX' does not exist). I can see this maybe a permissions issue since I am using an existing database. However, in that case, I should have been unable to create a table as well?

Can anyone pinpoint how I can work myself around this and what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your default schema?

```
SELECT name, default_schema_name 
    FROM sys.database_principals 
    WHERE type = 'S';
```

Try qualifying your references to the table as `SchemaName.XXX` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most of times when I had similar situations tables were created in system databases (master, tempdb..). Of course it was my  mistake.
So maybe try to search for a tables in other databases?